# Kile on Windows suddenly no longer compiles

Tags: kile

Apologies if this is not the correct place to ask this, since it is not exactly TeX specific...

I've been using Kile for a few years on my Windows 10 machine with no problem. After a Windows update, Kile suddenly no longer does anything. Upon opening Kile, I see `[LivePreview-PDFLaTeX] failed to start` in the messages window. Running a System Check, everything fails. For example, the test results show:

> LaTeX (Critical failure, Kile will not function properly)
>
> - Binary: Could not find the binary for this essential tool.

It worked fine last week until I installed a Windows update and restarted my computer. Otherwise nothing changed. I already uninstalled and reinstalled Kile, but that did not help.

What could have gone wrong, and what should I do to fix it?

---

**Edit**: I still do not know what the problem is, but I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Kile one more time. I started up Kile, but it still was not working. Then I ran the command `latex` in the command line and restarted Kile..... and it is working!?!??! Kile now finds the binaries with no problem.

This was nothing different from what I did yesterday, but today this fixed the problem.

Who knows!

Comment: Does compiling LaTeX documents from the command line work? Perhaps it's just a path issue.

Comment: I can run latex and pdftex just fine from the command prompt. I've also just installed texmaker, and I am able to compile just fine using texmaker.

Comment: have you updated any dependencies, e.g. `cygwin`?

Comment: Have you checked the Kile settings for missing/wrong paths?

Comment: @napheneal I just updated cygwin and restarted, but nothing has changed. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @siracusa How do I check for missing/wrong paths? I've tried going into `Configure Kile` under settings, but I can't find anything that would help with missing paths.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Kile. But it must either find its tools through the common path variable (in which case it should find all relevant binaries if it works from command line), or it must have a special setting for its tools. Doesn't the system check provide more information about the location(s) it has searched for the tools?

Comment: Not sure what happened, but today it is working! I have no idea what I did today that I did differently from how I tried to fix the problem in the last few days. Thanks anyway for the help.